# TestNG with eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32

Tags: java, testng-eclipse

Test output folder is not being created after I execute my test script using TestNG in eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2

Comment: What's your test script? See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It's a simple login page test script

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your eclipse then check folder will be there

Comment: This is the most common thing to refresh the eclipse after executing test script with TestNG. Question still remains the same.